# Lazy loading file in python, using with or just using for?

Tags: python

Would these two solutions be the same:

```py
def get_line(file_name):
    for line in open(file_name, "r"):
        yield line
```

```py
def get_line(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        yield f.readline()
```

We use `with` to auto-close a file, right? So what happens in the first example? How would one go about testing this functionality... I mean I usually mess about in the repl to understand things, but this time I get as far as verifying it's a generator but I don't know how to answer my own question given a repl.

In the case I'm working on atm I want to iterate over a large file twice, and I'll be using one of the above functions as a method on a class. Then, in two separate methods I will fully iterate through the file.

Comment: The first function loops through each line in the file. The second only reads one line.

Comment: There's no loop in the second version, so the iterator ends after the first line.

Comment: Thanks, I literally just verified that for myself hahah

Comment: Do I need to think about closing the file in the first version?

Comment: I think the garbage collector will eventually close the file, but it's better to be explicit. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code using `with` needs a loop:

```
def get_line(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Python ≥ 3.3, you can also write:

```
def get_line(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        yield from f
```